# Coderunner is not working

Tags: c, macos, compiler-construction, coderunner

I am having some problem with Coderunner. It was running with out any problem but now it is not.As you see in image below.

Please, can you help me to resolve this problem. Thanks!
http://yadi.sk/d/tDkp1K8v6aeby

Comment: Post the errors and description of what you were doing here instead of just an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you uninstall Xcode, or upgrade your OS recently ? Because Coderunner need Command Line Tool to work properly.

[How to install Command Line Tool for Lion and above.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540631/spwd-command-not-found-when-using-screen-on-os-x/17544875#17544875)