# "spwd: command not found" when using screen on OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, gnu-screen

Every time I issue a command in `screen` on OS X, I get the following error:

```
bash: spwd: command not found
```

I'm baffled. `spwd` seems to be available from bash, but not when I run `screen`. I'll admit I hadn't known about the existence of `spwd` until today (as I Googled this issue), so it's possible something else is going on.

System:

- OS X 10.8.4
- GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)
- Screen 4.00.03

Answer (score 0):

Since Lion, Command Line Tool isn't in a fresh install.

You have two options:

1. Download Xcode from the Mac App Store. Start Xcode, go to Preferences. In the General panel, you have Downloads and another one named Components. Finally click on Download button next to Command Line Tool
2. You can download the command line tools for Lion and Mountain Lion and other tools here: [Command Line Tool](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) (Developer account is needed)

Comment: Hmm. This doesn't fix the issue.